# How can I color cells based on list with conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

So I'm trying to make a few different lists with different colors and then I want google sheets color automatically whatever is on the list when it's shown elsewhere. I've been trying a few different ways and found a solution that kind of works but isn't really scalable.

I'm bad at explaining things, so hopefully this example does a greater job on that than I did
[Here's example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usfD6BaUGJgH9kj4PHICg-NcLYaJdL6YclG_nJgw0Hw/edit#gid=2089256886)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yellow list:**

```
=REGEXMATCH(G3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $B:$B))
```

**green list:**

```
=REGEXMATCH(G3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $C:$C))
```

**blue list:**

```
=REGEXMATCH(G3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $D:$D))
```

**red list:**

```
=REGEXMATCH(G3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $E:$E))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE

catfish fix:

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(G3), LOWER("^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, $B:$B)&"$"))
```